# 3D CSS Effect (max Cross Browser compatibility)

Tags: css

How would you make with CSS (and max Cross Browsers) an element like this?

[image]

Having this markup:

```
<ul>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
<ul>
```

Every `<li></li>` should be a box (in the image).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's simply a thick `outset` border, you don't need anything special for that:

```
li { border: 10px outset #CCC; }
```

[Here's a JsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/d8w5f8ns/).